# Formatted Date in calendar

Tags: asp.net-mvc, date, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a credit card expiration date picker that I've written, and there are very strict requirements, which sound simple, but I'm having a mental block or something.

I'm using the jquery-ui datepicker, submitting the form to an MVC Action.

In the form, the date needs to be shown in the textbox as mm/yy.

- 08/18
- 11/20
- 01/22

That is the requirement. They don't want *mm/yyyy*. They don't want *mm/dd/yy*… they very explicitly want *mm/yy*.

So my javascript is set up like this:

```
$('#expiry').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "mm/y"
}) 
.datepicker("option", "changeMonth", true)
.datepicker("option", "changeYear", true)
.datepicker("option", "showButtonPanel", true)
.datepicker("option", "onClose", function (e) {
    var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
    var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
    $(this).datepicker("setDate", new Date(year, month, 1));
});
```

And this appears appropriately in the form. But when I submit the form, the second set of digits is invariably transferred to the day of the month, and the **current** year is tacked on so I'm getting these dates with the above input samples:

- 08/18/2018
- 11/20/2018
- 01/22/2018

If I change the dateformat to "mm/yy", I get the right date on the back end, but it shows the 4 digit year, and I've been instructed that this simply isn't going to work.

I need the month, exactly 2 digits. I need the year exactly 2 digits, and nothing else. The day could be set to any random number between 1 and 29 for all I care, because I'm not going to use it.

Sounds simple. It's not. Do I need to write my own control for something so seemingly simple?

Comment: 08/18 or 11/20 is not a `DateTime`, and there is no real point using a datepicker (especially as the day is not appropriate). If you want to bind to, and save that value, then you will need 2 separate `int ExpiryMonth` and `int ExpiryYear` properties (and perhaps use dropdownlists in the UI)

Comment: 08/31/2018 is a date though - and that's fine in the back end, as long as it resolves to a DateTime - I just don't want to see it in the form. I only want to see the month and 2 digit year on the form. I'm sure it's possible as I can see 08/2018 on the form, and it resolves to a valid date on the back end.

Comment: No its not possible using a datepicker (unless you want to write some JavaScript hacks). Use 2 properties, one for `int ExpiryMonth` and one for `int ExpiryYear` (just as other sites that accept credit cards do).